# When using the fresco to load local images into RecyclerView, it's not smooth

Tags: android

The reason is likely my local image is too large, but impossible for me to scale every image in my cell phone. What can I do to solve this problem?

**item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="item"
            type="com.appbaba.digital.test.Test"/>
    </data>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
            android:id="@+id/simpleDraweeView"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            app:actualImageScaleType="centerCrop"
            app:placeholderImage="@mipmap/ic_place_holder"
            app:placeholderImageScaleType="centerCrop"
            app:progressBarAutoRotateInterval="3000"
            app:progressBarImage="@mipmap/ic_progress"
            app:progressBarImageScaleType="centerCrop"/>

    </FrameLayout>

</layout>
```

**recyclerView.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data
        class=".PhotoWallBinding"
        ></data>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/theme_primary">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/cl_bg_gravy"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include layout="@layout/title_bar"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

**JavaCode**

```
public class PhotoWallAty extends BaseAty<String> {
    private PhotoWallBinding photoWallBinding;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        photoWallBinding = (PhotoWallBinding) viewDataBinding;
    }

    @Override
    protected void initViews() {
        defaultTitleBar(this).setTitle("Albumn");
        recyclerView = photoWallBinding.recyclerView;
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    commonBinderAdapter.setIsScrolling(false);
                } else {
                    commonBinderAdapter.setIsScrolling(true);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            }
        });
        fillLatestImagePaths();

        commonBinderAdapter = new CommonBinderAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item_test, list) {
            @Override
            public void onBind(ViewDataBinding viewDataBinding, CommonBinderHolder holder, int
                    position, String s) {
                ItemTestBinding itemTestBinding = (ItemTestBinding) viewDataBinding;
                itemTestBinding.simpleDraweeView.setImageURI(Uri.parse("file://" + s));
            }
        };

        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 3, LinearLayoutManager
                .VERTICAL, true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(commonBinderAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void initEvents() {

    }

    @Override
    protected int getContentView() {
        return R.layout.aty_photo_wall;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onClick(int id, View view) {

    }

    private void fillLatestImagePaths() {
        list.clear();
        AppTools.showLoadingDialog(this);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int maxCount = 30;
                Uri mImageUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                String key_MIME_TYPE = MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE;
                String key_DATA = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA;
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(mImageUri, new String[]{key_DATA},
                        key_MIME_TYPE + "=? or " + key_MIME_TYPE + "=? or " + key_MIME_TYPE +
                                "=?", new
                                String[]{"image/png", "image/jpg", "image/jpeg"}, MediaStore
                                .Images.Media
                                .DATE_MODIFIED);
                if (cursor.moveToLast()) {
                    while (true) {
                        String path = cursor.getString(0);
                        if (!list.contains(path))
                            list.add(path);
                        if (list.size() > maxCount || !cursor.moveToPrevious()) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            switch (msg.what) {
                case 0:
                    AppTools.dismissLoadingDialog();
                    LogTools.e(list.get(0));
                    commonBinderAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

}
```

**Adapter**

```
public abstract class CommonBinderAdapter<T> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CommonBinderHolder> {

    protected Context context;
    protected List<T> list;
    protected int resId;
    protected BinderOnItemClickListener listener;
    protected CommonBinderHolder holder;
    protected Integer[] layouts = null;


    //Single layout
    public CommonBinderAdapter(Context context, int resId, List<T> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
        this.resId = resId;
    }

    //Multiple layout
    public CommonBinderAdapter(Context context, List<T> list, Integer... layouts) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
        this.layouts = layouts;
    }

    public CommonBinderAdapter(List<T> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public CommonBinderHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        ViewDataBinding binding;
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), resId,
                parent, false);
        holder = new CommonBinderHolder(binding, binding.getRoot(), listener);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CommonBinderHolder holder, int position) {
        onBind(holder.getBinding(), holder, position, list.get(position));
    }

    public abstract void onBind(ViewDataBinding viewDataBinding, CommonBinderHolder holder, int
            position, T t);

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public void setBinderOnItemClickListener(BinderOnItemClickListener listener) {
        if (listener != null)
            this.listener = listener;
    }

    public CommonBinderHolder getHolder() {
        return holder;
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to improve the formatting for readability. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I am part of the Fresco team and may be able to help.
Instead of setting just the Uri, specify the [resize](http://frescolib.org/docs/resizing-rotating.html#_) options. This will instruct Fresco to resize your image and will greatly improve performance when loading local camera images.